# How to move a Point perpendicular from nearest Line?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, point, analysis, line

I want to move Point perpendicular from nearest line or polygon, and the question is how to do that?

example, I have points (house number) near roadbed, and I don't want them to intersect roadbed (buffered street line)

I have used near analysis to get street line angle to the points for correct labeling, so the angle of the labels is really good but they are to close the road.

So I want to move the points perpendicular away from street line. is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the labels to be further away from the roadbed, why not offset the labels? No need to further manipulate the points feature.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Offsetting_point_labels/00s800000053000000/

You may also be be able to achieve this by creating a positive vertical offset in the text properties for your labels. This however, assumes that your label's baseline aligns with the roadbed (as opposed to the tops of your label text).